# Preserving leading "+" in CSV via Excel

Tags: python, csv, twilio

I have a python program that uses Twilio that I just moved from PKL databases to CSV. I read that the the access time was about the same, but wanted to leave it easier for editing.

Problem is Twilio likes a leading "+" for phone numbers (which I store in the database), but when editing in Excel it removes all of these leading plus signs.

What is the best way to handle phone number storage in python for Twilio?

```
def save_pkl(pkl, name):
    with open(os.path.join(__location__,name + '.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(pkl, f, 0) #replace 0 with pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL

def load_pkl(name):
    with open(os.path.join(__location__,name + '.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

def save_csv(obj, name):
    f=open(os.path.join(__location__,name+'.csv'),"wb")
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    if name=="customer":
        writer.writerow(("Name","MobileNumber","Email","Joined"))
        for number in obj:
            writer.writerow((obj[number]["name"],number,obj[number]["email"],obj[number]["joined"]))    
    else:
        writer.writerow(("Name","MobileNumber","Email"))
        for number in obj:
            writer.writerow((obj[number]["name"],number,obj[number]["email"]))
    f.close()

def load_csv(name):
    db={}
    f=open(os.path.join(__location__,name+'.csv'),"rb")
    headers = next(f).strip().split(",")
    freader = csv.reader(f)
    for entry in freader:
        name = entry[0]
        mobilenumber = entry[1]
        email = entry[2]
        db[mobilenumber]={"name" : name, "email" : email}
        if "Joined" in headers:
            joined = entry[3]
            db[mobilenumber]["joined"] = joined
    f.close()
    return db
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @xli I just added my pkl and csv load/save codes

Answer (score 1):

The tick before text to preserve interpretation of formulas in the cell first comes to mind and could be useful (`ex: '+33 445 455 333)`.

Except that in CSV it's not supported. It seems to work, but it's lost when saving to CSV. Extra quoting doesn't work either.

As an alternative, you could save your database in XLSX instead of CSV

- the leading tick does the job
- You could edit your file with Excel as easily
- python has at least 2 modules to handle properly XLSX: openpyxl and xlrd

(I hope you won't find my answer opinion based because it's true that there may exist several other valid solutions)

Comment: Thanks. I may try going to XLSX but need the patience to convert everything again. I wrote a python DB management program that manages the PKLs pretty well so may just keep that via easygui, but was hoping for an easier solution...

Comment: Does the tick not also work when the `csv` *dialect* is set to `excel`? Maybe you could try that.

Comment: seemed the logical thing to do, but it depends on your code of course.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: just tried: eats the "+" even with `dialect="excel"`. CSV is very limited.

Comment: The `dialect` only changes which characters are used to generate the file; it does not change how the application eventually handles it.

Comment: if someone finds a solution to this using CSV, I'll upvote with my 45 sock puppet accounts :)